# How to load a image into a picture box?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I Am programming in C# and I Already have it that I can select my files from my phone with this text:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var FileOpenPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    FileOpenPicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.List;
    FileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    FileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    FileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    FileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

How can I let the picture popup in the picturebox?

Comment: This is clearly not WinForms. Please retag accordinly.

Comment: @Alejandro: you can do it yourself, that's why you earn the tag edit privilege.

Comment: @Veverke Yes, but I'm not entirely sure what's the proper tag for it instead :D

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Comment: @Alejandro: truth is... neither do I :). Sorry Dave, I am not familiar with FileOpenPicker.

Comment: I'm not a Windows Phone? programmer.  Perhaps [How to continue your Windows Phone app after calling a file picker (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614994.aspx) would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `FileDialog` and load a bitmap from the selected path:

```
   using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    dlg.Title = "Open Image";
    dlg.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Create a new Bitmap object from the picture file on disk,
        // and assign that to the PictureBox.Image property
        PictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
    }
}
```